# How to escape a double-quote in inline c# script within javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How can I make the following inline c# work within javascript?  I have had no luck with escape characters, but I am sure I'm just doing something wrong.

```
var inputId = "<%= applicationForm.FindControl("myInput").ClientID %>";
```

Comment: Unless the ClientID-property contains a quote, your code is fine. Or at lease the line you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use *single quotes* in JavaScript to define [String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Literals#String_Literals):

```
var inputId = '<%= applicationForm.FindControl("myInput").ClientID %>';
```

Answer (score 2):

your line should work.
try this too:

```
var inputId = '<%= applicationForm.FindControl("myInput").ClientID %>';
```